# Microsoft Azure Worker Role or Azure Scheduler for Backup and Restore?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-webjobs

Creating Backup and restore Azure Table Storage Scheduler, where user will schedule the job or task to backup Azure Table at particular time, from Wizard. Which way I must Prefer?

1. Should I use Azure Service i.e Creating WebRole and Worker Role.
         In this case how to Execute Worker Role on Schedule.
2. Can I use Web Job with Scheduler?
3. How to use Azure Scheduler to achive this task? I have googled out
   where in some blogs they suggested to use Scheduler with Azure
   Queue.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Azure Scheduler.  If your are familiar with a Cron job, this is very similar.  All the Azure Scheduler does is make a REST call to an end point on a schedule.  This would probably be more cost affective then setting up a worker role.  Also, I would make sure to take into account security when setting up the Azure Scheduler.  I would pass some type of secret to the API as a parameter so that it's not open to anonymous calls (although technically it would be.)  If you want to execute certain tasks during the call, then I would store them in a table in your database.  The worker role came before the Azure Scheduler, so the worker role lost in my book when the scheduler was made public.

UPDATE:

Another thought, is to look into the automation option in Azure:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn643629.aspx

With this option you can execute PowerShell scripts:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/20/azure-automation-capabilities-in-depth-the-azure-automation-powershell-cmdlets/

Comment: Thanks a lot for Reply, I was thinking to use Worker role for folowing Scenario : if there are many schedules for backup in small timespan, and if i keep Worker role as auto scale then it will create its instance automatically and handle the overload. Will this scenario will work with Rest Call. or will there be any hurdle if i use Rest Call. plz let me know i am very Confused. Thanks Rogala for ur Help in Advance.

Comment: @vishal Sorry for the delayed response, I was sick.  I wouldn't be able to advice on which to choose, because I don't know enough about your system to make an educated decision.  What I can tell you is that the Azure Scheduler makes calls to an endpoint, so if you already have a web role, you could setup an endpoint to handle these calls.  This would be more economical then having a web role and worker role.  It also would be easier to manage.  As far as the overload, you could then setup you web role to auto-scale.  I would look at your current utilization to figure out what makes sense.

Comment: @vishal Tonight, I will add some code to how you use the Azure Scheduler to run code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either. Azure WebJobs are simpler and easier to use and would work well for your scenario.
You can use Azure WebJob with Azure Scheduler. You can set the schedule ahead of time where the scheduler will trigger the WebJob where you can perform your backup task.

Please see these articles

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/#configure

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduled